# During XML Parsing in VBA, how to display Parent Node of a Child Node

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have a XML that I am parsing in VBA and it looks like below:

```
<PEFPDetails>
  <PEFP>
    <UniqueIdentifier>sfdkfsd</UniqueIdentifier>
    <Surname>A1</Surname>
    <FirstName>F1</FirstName>
    <CountryText>Canada</CountryText>
    <PEOrganizationText>Bank</PEOrganizationText>
  </PEFP>
</PEFPDetails>
<PEDPDetails>
  <PEDP>
    <UniqueIdentifier>afdsfdsg</UniqueIdentifier>
    <Surname>fdsf</Surname>
    <FirstName>wqepwe</FirstName>
    <CountryText>Canada</CountryText>
    <PEOrganizationText>msdlkfds</PEOrganizationText>
  </PEDP>
</PEDPDetails>
```

As you can see, every child node of PEFP and PEDP share the same node-name.

This is the code that I am using:

```vb
Sub IterateThruElements()
    Dim xmlDoc      As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xmlNode     As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim myNode      As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    ' Create an Instance of the DOMDocument
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.async = False

    ' Load XML information from a file. In this case, Cell C3 of Sheet "XML & DB2 Data" should contain the path of the XML
    strPathToXMLFile = Sheets("Credentials").Range("C3").Value
    xmlDoc.Load (strPathToXMLFile)

    ' Find out the number of child nodes in the file
    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")

    ' Open a new workbook and paste the data
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "TempSheet_1"
    Range("A1:B1").Formula = Array("Element Name", "Text")

    For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList

        For Each myNode In xmlNode.ChildNodes
            If myNode.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Formula = xmlNode.nodeName
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = xmlNode.Text
            End If
        Next myNode

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next xmlNode
End Sub
```

This is what I am getting:

```
UniqueIdentifier
Surname
FirstName
CountryText
PEOrganizationText

UniqueIdentifier
Surname
FirstName
CountryText
PEOrganizationText
```

Is there any way by which I can add Parent Node to distinguish  the child nodes?

Comment: Can you include a valid XML sample?  You can validate using a tool such as https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator In this case it means including the root node as a minimum.

Comment: As QHarr says... This XML needs, at the very least, an xml declaration and a root element. Without that it's difficult / impossible to give you an answer since the optimal approach may not be "backwards". I'm assuming you're not using a namespace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your XML structure remains constant, the node you're looking for is two levels "up" from the *Text* node, so:

```
myNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.BaseName
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer given already. I will add that validate on parse is useful to warn you of loading invalid XML.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub IterateThruElements()
    Dim xmlDoc      As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim xmlNode     As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim myNode      As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    ' Create an Instance of the DOMDocument
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.async = False

    Dim strPathToXMLFile As String
    ' Load XML information from a file. In this case, Cell C3 of Sheet "XML & DB2 Data" should contain the path of the XML
    strPathToXMLFile = Sheets("Credentials").Range("C3").Value
    xmlDoc.validateOnParse = True

    If Not xmlDoc.Load(strPathToXMLFile) Then 
        MsgBox "Problem"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Find out the number of child nodes in the file
    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*")

    ' Open a new workbook and paste the data
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "TempSheet_1"
    Range("A1:B1").Formula = Array("Element Name", "Text")

    For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
        For Each myNode In xmlNode.ChildNodes
            If myNode.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Formula = myNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.BaseName & ":" & xmlNode.nodeName
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = xmlNode.Text
            End If
        Next myNode

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next xmlNode
End Sub
```